# Change index.html for index.jsp (JavaEE+Glassfish)

Tags: jsp, web-applications, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I have a little problem.
Is it possible 'delete' index.html and create (to replace index.html) index.jsp? How?

I don't find any files (web.xml, glassfish-resource.xml) with the address to the home page (index.html) to change it (for index.jsp).
I have not found an answer on the Internet...

Thanks for replies!

Comment: thanks for this question. i was trying to serve `index.xhtml` but couldn't figure out how. the accepted answer to this question `welcome-file-list` element helped me too. remains next is how to serve `xhtml` via `.jsp`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is to configure the welcome-file-list for your application. By default, it's index.html, which is why you don't find anything defining it.

Take a look at [web.xml Deployment Descriptor Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1026980)  You basically need

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Thank you all!
Adrian's answer worked for me.
The mini-example was very useful:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/components.html#109211

Just today I started with this. Time to read the Oracle documentation.
Thank you again!

Comment: isn't web.xml outmoded?  annotations are preferred, I believe.

Comment: It is definitely more convenient to use annotations in many cases, but AFAIK there's no way you can customize the welcome file list using annotations. Think about it this way: while it makes sense to define annotation in the servlet class to describe metadata that used to live in the web.xml, there's no class you can add annotations for in order to describe global information such as the welcome file list.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete index.html then index.jsp will automatically take over for requests to `http://yourserver/yourapp/`.

Do you have the problem of users having bookmarked `http://yourserver/yourapp/index.html` itself so you need backwards compatibility? You can map index.jsp to respond to requests for index.html in web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>indexhtml</servlet-name> 
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>indexhtml</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You could also use *.html there to have index.jsp respond to all requests for any .html:

```
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Thanks "If you delete index.html then index.jsp will automatically take over" is so simple and works for me in 2021.