# Transferred from Netbeans to Eclipse, now "Severe: PWC6117: File "null" not found"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans

I transferred my Java maven netbeans glassfish web application to Eclipse. It consists of a .jsp and some controller servlets for when the user clicks on stuff.

It runs in Netbeans (i rightclick the jsp and run it, and the webpage loads). Some functionality in some controller methods is broken but the webpage still opens fine when i run it.

In Eclipse, I rightclick the jsp and run on server and get the following (scroll to end):

```
2015-04-20T09:09:28.066+0100|Info: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
2015-04-20T09:09:28.068+0100|Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2015-04-20T09:09:28.379+0100|Info: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-04-20T09:09:28.380+0100|Info: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-04-20T09:09:28.385+0100|Info: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2015-04-20T09:09:28.609+0100|Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2015-04-20T09:09:29.171+0100|Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2015-04-20T09:09:29.894+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 458ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
2015-04-20T09:09:30.073+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:30.286+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 335ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
2015-04-20T09:09:30.360+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 37ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
2015-04-20T09:09:30.410+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
2015-04-20T09:09:30.771+0100|Info: Java security manager is disabled.
2015-04-20T09:09:30.773+0100|Info: Entering Security Startup Service.
2015-04-20T09:09:30.776+0100|Info: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
2015-04-20T09:09:30.823+0100|Info: Security Service(s) started successfully.
2015-04-20T09:09:31.041+0100|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2015-04-20T09:09:31.052+0100|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2015-04-20T09:09:31.055+0100|Info: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2015-04-20T09:09:31.080+0100|Info: Created virtual server server
2015-04-20T09:09:31.090+0100|Info: Created virtual server __asadmin
2015-04-20T09:09:31.348+0100|Info: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
2015-04-20T09:09:31.349+0100|Info: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
2015-04-20T09:09:32.301+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:32.455+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:32.476+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:32.481+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:32.482+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:32.763+0100|Info: Portable JNDI names for EJB Info: [java:global/animelist1/Info, java:global/animelist1/Info!entities.Info]
2015-04-20T09:09:32.825+0100|Info: Portable JNDI names for EJB AnnJAXB: [java:global/animelist1/AnnJAXB, java:global/animelist1/AnnJAXB!main.AnnJAXB]
2015-04-20T09:09:32.836+0100|Info: Portable JNDI names for EJB Ann: [java:global/animelist1/Ann!entities.Ann, java:global/animelist1/Ann]
2015-04-20T09:09:32.850+0100|Info: Portable JNDI names for EJB Anime: [java:global/animelist1/Anime!entities.Anime, java:global/animelist1/Anime]
2015-04-20T09:09:32.884+0100|Info: WELD-000900: 2.2.2 (Final)
2015-04-20T09:09:33.140+0100|Info: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
2015-04-20T09:09:33.413+0100|WARN: WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2015-04-20T09:09:33.414+0100|WARN: WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2015-04-20T09:09:33.606+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2015-04-20T09:09:33.622+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2015-04-20T09:09:33.646+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2015-04-20T09:09:34.749+0100|Info: Loading application [animelist1] at [/animelist1]
2015-04-20T09:09:34.753+0100|Info: Loading application animelist1 done in 5,562 ms
2015-04-20T09:09:34.769+0100|Info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (2,265ms), startup services(6,789ms), total(9,054ms)
2015-04-20T09:09:35.197+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 130ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
2015-04-20T09:09:35.284+0100|Info: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@4ae263bf as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@49a71302.
2015-04-20T09:09:35.354+0100|Info: C:\Program Files\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\bundles does not exist, please create it.
2015-04-20T09:09:36.159+0100|Info: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://J-PC:8686/jndi/rmi://J-PC:8686/jmxrmi
2015-04-20T09:09:36.234+0100|Info: keepstate options resolved to true, saving appId 93684827868430336 for application animelist1.
2015-04-20T09:09:36.840+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:37.021+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:37.036+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:37.047+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:37.048+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:37.049+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-04-20T09:09:37.153+0100|Info: Portable JNDI names for EJB AnnJAXB: [java:global/animelist1/AnnJAXB, java:global/animelist1/AnnJAXB!main.AnnJAXB]
2015-04-20T09:09:37.169+0100|Info: Portable JNDI names for EJB Ann: [java:global/animelist1/Ann!entities.Ann, java:global/animelist1/Ann]
2015-04-20T09:09:37.186+0100|Info: Portable JNDI names for EJB Anime: [java:global/animelist1/Anime!entities.Anime, java:global/animelist1/Anime]
2015-04-20T09:09:37.201+0100|Info: Portable JNDI names for EJB Info: [java:global/animelist1/Info, java:global/animelist1/Info!entities.Info]
2015-04-20T09:09:37.302+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2015-04-20T09:09:37.315+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2015-04-20T09:09:37.327+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2015-04-20T09:09:38.201+0100|Info: Loading application [animelist1] at [/animelist1]
2015-04-20T09:09:38.252+0100|Info: animelist1 was successfully deployed in 2,101 milliseconds.
2015-04-20T09:09:38.680+0100|Severe: PWC6117: File "null" not found
```

I am brand new to Eclipse, and new to programming. Is there something I might have needed to alter when opening the project in eclipse? It was a maven project and i opened it with maven in eclipse, everything went smoothly.

Alternatively, is there a way I can find more detail about the error? When I google `PWC6117: File "null" not found` it seems to be specific errors in peoples code and my code was working fine on netbeans so i'm not sure how to narrow it down

Thankyou

Comment: I tried finally to type "http://localhost:8080/animelist1/" instead of the default "http://localhost:8080/index.jsp" . I don't know why but it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it was to do with my [welcome file not being defined.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705519/change-index-html-for-index-jsp-javaeeglassfish)
In your situation it may've been define in Netbeans but not in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Since your context has loaded, your application will always be loaded with the following url pattern

`protocol//:hostname:port/context-name`

Refer [How to set the context](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html) for your web application. By default context name is your project name. However you can change whatever you want in the `web.xml` file.

So you'll have to load the application using the url,

`http://localhost:8080/animelist1`

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there it is an `index.jsp` in the `WEB-INF/jsp/` folder. Or whatever you set as a welcome file in the `web.xml`.